# Why does this if statement not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have some divs that I use jQuery's fade in/out to bring onto the page when a link is clicked. Each page has an associated html5 audio element that also fades in/out accordingly.

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
    var targetpage = $($(this).attr("href"));
    $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(0); //fade out currently displayed page
    targetpage.fadeIn(); //fade in page associated with link
    if (targetpage.children().hasClass('backgroundmusic')) {
        $('audio').animate({volume: 0}, 1000); //fade out currently playing audio
        alert('audio faded out');
        $.each($('audio'), function () { //stop all audio
            this.currentTime=0;
            this.pause();
            alert('audio stopped');
        });
        alert('stop function executed');
    }
});

$('.sound').on('play', function () { //since volume was faded out, reset volume when click play button
    $('audio').animate({volume: 1}, 100);
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#page1" class="link">Audio 1</a>
<a href="#page2" class="link">Audio 2</a>
<a href="#page3" class="link">Audio 3</a>

<div class="pagecontainer">

<div id="page1"> //all three audio elements are in exact same spot
                 //clicking page link fades in current audio and fades in new one
    <div class="backgroundmusic">
    <audio controls loop class="sound" preload="none">
        <source src="../../site/music/music1.mp3"/>
        <source src="../../site/music/music1.ogg"/>
    </audio>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page2">
    <div class="backgroundmusic">
    <audio controls loop class="sound" preload="none">
        <source src="../../site/music/music2.mp3"/>
        <source src="../../site/music/music2.ogg"/>
    </audio>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page3">
    <div class="backgroundmusic">
    <audio controls loop class="sound" preload="none">
        <source src="../../site/music/music3.mp3"/>
        <source src="../../site/music/music3.ogg"/>
    </audio>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The "alert('audio faded out')" will execute, but the "alert('audio stopped')" **does not execute** as it's not running the "$.each($('audio'), function" script at all, neither does "alert('stop function executed')". I have to use this "each" script as $('audio').currentTime=0 does not work, neither does $('audio').pause(), as I have multiple audio instances on my page.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You pass in `e` to your function but don't use it. Probably want to prevent default action from that click event.

```
e.preventDefault(); //Put this at the top of the callback
```

This should fix your .each() problems. Also you should be using the console instead of alerts as to not freeze your page.

```
console.log('audio faded out'); //Use console instead of alerts
$('audio').each(function () { //Do it this way.
    this.currentTime=0;
    this.pause();
    console.log('audio stopped');
});
console.log('stop function executed');
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I found out that only the audio on page1 stops correctly. Page2 and 3 doesn't seem to work with that script. I was told it might have something to do with you can't stop/pause/reset audio that hasn't loaded yet, and for some reason whichever audio element appears first in the DOM will load... Still looking for a fix for this. I can't have all of them load automatically (ie, delete `preload="auto"`), that would cause google Chrome to hang as I've got like 20 mp3/ogg's on my website trying to load at the same time.

Comment: You can set them to load in a queue. If you use something like AJAX with jQuery's built in queue you can load all of them asynchronously - one at a time. No hang, just a bang.